# GoodData "Create Report Definition" API Call giving 500 Internal Server Error

Tags: rest, gooddata

I'm trying to create a report definition using the GoodData REST API. I use the following endpoint to invoke the rest call.

> "/gdc/md/{project-id}/obj"

When i try to invoke the API call with the following dataset in which the projectId and the userId are valid, it gives me the error with the response code 500.

```
{
 "reportDefinition": {
    "content": {
    "filters": [],
    "format": "grid",
    "grid": {
        "rows": [],
        "columns": [
            "metricGroup"
        ],
        "sort": {
            "columns": [],
            "rows": []
        },
        "columnWidths": [],
        "metrics": [
            {
                "uri": "/gdc/md/qy48iv4flikdlcwpwioizuip74wt8nb5/obj/63f3cecd2a8d3ce2ec9378381c8f39e3",
                "alias": ""
            }
        ]
    }
},
"meta": {
    "title": "Sample report definition",
    "summary": "This is a sample report",
    "tags": "",
    "deprecated": 0,
    "category": "samplecategory"
    }
  }
} 

{
    "error": {
        "message": "Internal server error. Please fill in bug report with request_id='lp78FL5S1IPMqB2n'"
    }
}
```

I'm certain that the user project_id and the user_id are valid. Is this an error in the API?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Apart from the metrics URI that looks weird (hash instead of numeric ID), I was able to dig in our logs an error that says: "Category is not equal to tag structure".

In your example you have its value set to "samplecategory". "category" property defines what type of object are you creating. If you are creating a report definition it should have value of "reportDefinition".

Answer (score 0):

Last time I worked with GoodData API, metrics had numeric IDs. That seems most likely to be the culprit. Where did you get "/gdc/md/qy48iv4flikdlcwpwioizuip74wt8nb5/obj/63f3cecd2a8d3ce2ec9378381c8f39e3" from, especially the "63f3cecd2a8d3ce2ec9378381c8f39e3" part?